# ember-app-kit and require.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, requirejs, aloha-editor, ember-app-kit

I am trying to integrate the aloha editor into an ember-app-kit application. Aloha uses require.js to load its dependencies. I include the aloha folder into the vendor directory of the ember-app-kit. When the site starts to load it complains that require.config is undefined (I see that in the Chromium console). I think it is because of the way ember-app-kit loads its modules, but that is just a guess. Should this work or is it not possible to mix ES6 and require.js?

Best regards
Greg